# How to change the camera position during design in Viewport3D?

Tags: delphi, 3d, firemonkey, delphi-xe

In Delphi 10.x for arrange objects in the environment, How to change the position of the default camera or zoom it during design?

Comment: Is it not a simple case of setting the properties of the camera (Position, RotationAngle)? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Viewport3D.TViewport3D.Camera . http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Controls3D.TCamera

Comment: Yes , it is! but...
it is for runtime not desing time.It seems that can not be done at the time of design

Comment: OK. It seems easy enough though. I started a new FMX project and added a TViewport3D to the form. I then added a TCamera to the form from the 3D Scene tab and set the Position and RotationAngle. I then set the Camera property for ViewPort3D1 to Camera1 to link them.

Comment: yes you can change the Position and RotationAngle but see defualt camera, The default view is displayed until the program runs

Comment: OK, but why do you need to see the correct view at design time?

Comment: Because the environment I create is large and I do not have a complete view of objects, I started writing 3D design editor